# Generate unique string key based on properties of object (cachekey)

Tags: c#

I am simply trying to generate a unique cachekey that takes in the object type and property values
GetHashCode returns different results each time so that wont work, so I have to implement a solution but it has to be fast (I can go through the properties and and concat their values to a string but this might be slow and not the best way to go about it)

Nice To Have:
so if 2 different object types have the exact same properties and same values but they are different classes, they should be different cachekeys (chances of this happening are very slim but just in case)

Here is my code

```
public interface ICachableRequest
{
    string GetCacheKey();
}

public class Object1 : ICachableRequest
{
    public int IntValue1 { get; set; }
    public double DoubleVal1 { get; set; }
    public string  StringVal1 { get; set; }
    public string GetCacheKey()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Object2 : ICachableRequest
{
    public int SomeIntValue1 { get; set; }
    public double SomeOtherDoubleVal1 { get; set; }
    public string MoreStringVal1 { get; set; }

    public string MoreStringVal2 { get; set; }
    public string MoreStringVal3 { get; set; }
    public string MoreStringVal4 { get; set; }

    public string GetCacheKey()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd just concatenate the typename, and the names and values (.ToString()) of all the properties together and then hash the result.  You could even do this from outside the class pretty simply using reflection.

Comment: What is the point of this cache key? If you need to know all values in the object to be able to calculate the key you wouldn't need to look it up in the cache, since you already know all there is to know about the object - so you wouldn't need the cache, right?

Comment: @Flydog57 I would imagine reflection would be slow so thats why i didnt go that route

Comment: @Xerillio they cachekey to look up the cached value of the request, I simply want to be able to only go to the database if that "request" has not been cached in memory/redis so this was my attempt at avoiding multiple database calls for the same request

Comment: Isn't the hashcode of its own `typeof` good enough?